# Rails controller method to show an optionally scaled image using MiniMagick

Tags: ruby, image, ruby-on-rails

I've got below implementation for my controller and show action which implements `MiniMagick` gem. I've just wondering is there any better way to write it down? If block in a separate, private method maybe?

```
  def show
    identification_document = IdentificationDocument.find(params[:id])
    authorize identification_document
    return unless identification_document

    if params.has_key?(:thumbnail)
      document = identification_document.id_document
      image = MiniMagick::Image.read(document.file.read)
      image.resize("50x60")
      scaled_image_bytes = image.to_blob
      send_data(scaled_image_bytes, filename: identification_document.file_name)
    else 
      send_data(identification_document.id_document.file.read, filename: identification_document.file_name)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Rubocop Report

#### Conventions

Prefer `key?` over `has_key?` ([PreferredHashMethods](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/PreferredHashMethods)).

> ```
> if params.has_key?(:thumbnail)
> ```

```
if params.key?(:thumbnail)
```

---

Prefer single quoted over double quoted string literals if you don't need interpolation or special symbols ([StringLiterals](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/StringLiterals)).

> ```
> image.resize("50x60")
> ```

```
image.resize('50x60')
```

---

#### Complexity

> *If block in a separate, private method maybe?*

The [AbcSize](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Metrics/AbcSize) complexity of your method is too high. [19.65/15] So your suggestion to put the following code in a private method, is justified.

> ```
>  document = identification_document.id_document
>  image = MiniMagick::Image.read(document.file.read)
>  image.resize("50x60")
>  scaled_image_bytes = image.to_blob
> ```

---

#### Readability

Keep line sizes below 80 characters:

> ```
> send_data(identification_document.id_document.file.read, filename: identification_document.file_name)
> ```

Comment: The under 80 chars rule is outdated. Screens have gotten significantly bigger and more pixels are available. There should definitely be a max char length enforced, but it can easily be 120 or 150 depending on the developers setups in an organization.

Comment: Single quote vs double quote is against the rails convention. Rails convention is double quotes all around, so I would suggest keeping the double quotes.

Comment: @ekampp Thanks for the feedback, you have a link to more recent guidelines, or are you talking out of personal experience?

Comment: regarding the 80 char rule, that's from experience. The Rails convention if from reading the Rails documentation and source code.